# Syntax error for link in nested content_tag :div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I'm new to rails. I'm trying to add a link to a div that is being generated with the content_tag. I'm getting a syntax error but I can't seem to figure out why.

I used this [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    = content_tag :div, msg content_tag(:a, "Close", :href => '', :class => 'close'), :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => 'alert-box alert'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to produce something like `<div>msg <a>Close</a></div>`?

Comment: Yes. I should've mentioned that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to concatenate `msg` with your `content_tag :a`. try this:

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    = content_tag :div, 
                  "#{msg} #{content_tag(:a, 'Close', :href => '', :class => 'close')}",
                  :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => 'alert-box alert'
```

*hint:* 
you can [use a block](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) with `content_tag` to improve readability.

```
content_tag :div do
  # the content of this block will be captured
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I did have to make it html_safe. Please update your sample incase another n00b comes across this ;)